# mongoDB query with case insensitive schema element

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In my MongoDB collection I have added a record as follows

```
db.teacher.insert({_id:1 ,"name":"Kaushik"})
```

If I search

```
db.teacher.find({name:"Kaushik"})
```

I get one record. But if I try "NAME" instead of "name" i.e.

```
db.teacher.find({NAME:"Kaushik"})
```

It won't return any record.

It means that I must know how schema element is spelled exactly with exact case. Is there way to write query by ignoring case of schema element.

We can search the element value using case insensitive as follows

```
> db.teacher.find({name:/kAUSHIK/i})
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Kaushik" }
```

Is there similar for schema element; something like

```
> db.teacher.find({/NAME/i:"kaushik"})
```

Comment: Not in a good way there isn't. You can write up all the matching in JavaScript but it cannot use indexes or other optimized native features Why would you want to do this anyway? I know MongoDB is schemaless, but still your names of elements should not vary in case between documents just as much as it isn't wise to generally vary structure or types between documents.

Comment: How about simply using all lowercase or camelcase keys? Problem solved.

Comment: @user3561036  while adding into collection I myself made mistake where I used "name" in one document and "Name" in other. This can happen for some other element "studenId"/"studentid". I agree that element name should be consistent. But for some reason; if they are not; then is there way to handle it; is what I was curious about.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg could not understand your suggestion.

Comment: @KaushikLele How to handle it is "fix" the incorrect entries. And as for answers here, despite one being "upvoted" and accepted, nothing here even attempts to explain how to "fix" this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We can search the element value using case insensitive [...]
>
> Is there [something] similar for schema element [?]

No.

---

We may assume that JavaScript and JSON are case sensitive, and so are MongoDB queries.

That being said, internally MongoDB uses BSON, and [the specs](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) say nothing about case-sensitivity of keys. The BNF grammar only said that an element name is a nul terminated [modified UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) string:

```
e_name      ::=     cstring            Key name
cstring     ::=     (byte*) "\x00"     Zero or more modified UTF-8 encoded
                                       characters followed by '\x00'. The
                                       (byte*) MUST NOT contain '\x00', hence
                                       it is not full UTF-8.
```

But, from the source code ([here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/bson/bsonelement.cpp#L385) or [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/bson/bsonmisc.cpp#L46) for example), it appears that MongoDB BSON's implementation use `strcmp` to perform binary comparison on element names, confirming there is no way to achieve what you want.

This might be indeed an issue beyond case sensitivity, as using [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), the same character might have several binary representations -- but MongoDB does not perform  [Unicode normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization). For example:

```
> db.collection.insert({"é":1})
> db.collection.find({"é":1}).count()
1
> db.collection.find({"e\u0301":1}).count()
0
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Do you think it is worth to report this problem to mongoDB; in case they have not already marked it as "known limitation".

Answer (score 0):

This related to javascript engine and json specification. in js identifiers are case sensitive. This means you can have a document with two field named "name" and "Name" or "NAME". So mongodb act as two distinct filed with your fields.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a regex like

db.teacher.find({name:/^kaushik$/i})

Comment: I had asked about case-insensitivity of schema element and not for value.